# What toolkit in Python can achieve the effect as shown in the figure

Tags: python

I'd like to draw a three-dimensional trajectory that can show the attitude of the plane as shown in the figure. What toolkit in Python I should learn?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is 3D Line plots of Matplotlib.

To help you get started, you can refer to this Blog: [An easy introduction to 3D plotting with Matplotlib](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-easy-introduction-to-3d-plotting-with-matplotlib-801561999725)

The official Tutorial of matplotlib 3D Plots can be found here: [Matplotlib 3D Tutorial - Lines](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/toolkits/mplot3d.html)

If you want to explore more, a very good resource to different types of Graph Plots along with code examples can be found here: [Python Graph Gallery](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

the standard plotting library in python (pretty much) is Matplotlib. It contains a 3D API called mplot3d.
For an example, see here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html

The example you are showing does look a lot like it was created with Matplotlib. Other options include seaborn and bokeh. Your choice what to use, really.